# Woocommerce variable protect "No products matched your selection"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Recently a site we built that was working just fine has had a issue with one of it's products. viewing the products gives the message `Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination`. While also not being able to select a new option.

**I've so far done the following:**

1. Checked every option for the product/admin to the working dev site, there were no differences.
2. Deleted the variations, deleted the attributes, then recreated the attributes and variations on the product.
3. Tried to create a new product wit the same options.
4. Updated the woocommerce databass (There was a notice satying it needed doing but the plugin was not updated).

I had assumed this was because of an update to wordpress recently but going back to a backup a few days before this was reported there were no differences between the files.

After extensive googling the only issues i can see like this are from incorrect options selected, or for a similar error with products not displaying in categories, but the product was working and no changes seem to ave been made to the product or the files.

this is occuring with **WordPress 4.3.1** and **WooCommerce 2.4.7**

Answer (score 7):

If you have over 30 variations, you need to increased the number of allowed variations in your functions.php:

```
/**
 * Ensure variation combinations are working properly - standard limit is 30
 * 
 */

function woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 50;
}       
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This is the answer, thank you! Just make sure you make the return number higher than your number of variations.

Answer (score 3):

Have you copied any of the WooCommerce templates in your theme folder? If so you'll need to update them with the new versions from the WooCommerce plugin folder. I had a similar problem and had to update the /theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php.